# Java FX 2.2 tableview data changes as I scroll up and down the tableview

Tags: javafx-2

I have used a tableView in JavaFX2.2. I have a column where I have kept values which are updated when the user clicks on a button. These values are dynamically getting populated and till this part its working fine. However, when I scroll down the table to see the other values in the table, the cell data changes. Can you please suggest what I need to do to get this problem resolved?

Here is the code for the table cell that I am dynamically populating and is getting changed on scrolling down the table.

```
        Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactoryField = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {                

        @Override
        public TableCell call(final TableColumn param) {
            final Button button = new Button("Select Field");                    
            final TableCell cell = new TableCell() {

                @Override
                public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
//                                label.setText("Here");                            
                    if (empty) {
//                                System.out.println("table cell inside updateitem = "+item);
//                                setGraphic(null);
                    }
                    else
                    {      

                    }
                }
            };
            button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                private CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkBoxTreeItem;
                private CheckBoxTreeItem<String> nodeFieldName;
                private CheckBoxTreeItem<String> nodeFieldName2;
                private CheckBoxTreeItem<String> nodeFieldName3;
                private Stage stage = new Stage();

                @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                    CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem = 
                        new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Tables");                            
                    rootItem.setExpanded(true);                  

                    final TreeView tree = new TreeView(rootItem);  
                    tree.setEditable(true);

                    tree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String>forTreeView());                                                            
                    {
                        checkBoxTreeItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Sample Table" );//+ (i+1));                                
                        rootItem.getChildren().add(checkBoxTreeItem);                                                
                        nodeFieldName = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Field Name1");                                
                        nodeFieldName2 = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Field Name2");
                        nodeFieldName3 = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Field Name3");
                        checkBoxTreeItem.getChildren().addAll(nodeFieldName, nodeFieldName2, nodeFieldName3);                    

                    }                                    
                    tree.setRoot(rootItem);
                    tree.setShowRoot(true);                            
                    StackPane root = new StackPane();                                
                    root.getChildren().add(tree);
                    Button selectButton = new Button("Select");
                    HBox hbox = new HBox();
                    hbox.getChildren().add(selectButton);
                    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                    selectButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

                        @Override
                        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {

                            final ArrayList<String> selectedValues = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     //                                    System.out.println("Selected tree items are : ");
                            if(checkBoxTreeItem.isSelected())
                                selectedValues.add(checkBoxTreeItem.getValue());
                            if(nodeFieldName.isSelected())
                                selectedValues.add(nodeFieldName.getValue());
                            if(nodeFieldName2.isSelected())
                                selectedValues.add(nodeFieldName2.getValue());
                            if(nodeFieldName3.isSelected())
                                selectedValues.add(nodeFieldName3.getValue());                               
                            stage.hide();                                
                            for(int i = 0; i<selectedValues.size();i++)
                            {
                                if(i == selectedValues.size()-1)
                                    selectedVals += selectedValues.get(i);    
                                else                                            
                                    selectedVals += selectedValues.get(i)+",";    
                            }
                            fieldNameChosen = true;
                            if(fieldNameChosen)
                                cell.setGraphic(new Label(selectedVals));
                            else
                                cell.setGraphic(button);
                        }
                    });
                    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
                    borderPane.setCenter(root);
                    borderPane.setBottom(hbox);
                    stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(borderPane)));                             
                    stage.show();
                }
            });
            if(!(cell.getGraphic() instanceof Label))
                cell.setGraphic(button);
            return cell;
        }
    };
    fieldName.setCellFactory(cellFactoryField);
```

I am getting a similar problem for another field where I need to show values from another table dynamically. Below is the code I have used.

```
              final int k = 0;  
    value.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        int noOfDataCells = k;
        public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) 
        {                    

            TableColumn column = param.getTableColumn();
            int size = 0;
            if(tableView1.getItems()!=null)
                size = ((ObservableList) tableView1.getItems().get(0)).size();
            String valueFromData = "";
            if(noOfDataCells<size)
            {
                valueFromData = String.valueOf(((ObservableList) tableView1.getItems().get(0)).get(noOfDataCells));                                                               
            }
            else if(noOfDataCells == size)
            {
                noOfDataCells = 0;
                valueFromData = String.valueOf(((ObservableList) tableView1.getItems().get(0)).get(noOfDataCells));  
            }
            else if (noOfDataCells>size)
            {
                valueFromData = "";
            }
            noOfDataCells++;
            //TODO SET THE VALUE IN THE MODEL
```

//                ((MetaTag) column.getTableView().getItems().get(
//                        .getIndex())).setFieldName(selectedVals);

```
            return new SimpleStringProperty(valueFromData);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I've run your code sample with JavaFX 2.2 and it worked fine. Can you elaborate how "the cell data changes" in your case?

Comment: The data is displayed fine when I select the data first time. Then if I scroll up and down the table, the data changes in the cells.

Comment: Each cell is showing values at random. For some cells its showing the button and for some others it is showing the value which was selected. But the value is not displayed against the correct cell. I hope its clear now. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Any clue how I can solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are next problem:

1. You are using table editing functionality without implementing required API
2. You update cells in your factory, but not a data by which Table is backed up by
3. Cells are being destroyed on scroll out (for performance reason) and recreated back, so all your changes become destroyed.

See next tutorial on correct approach to TableView editing: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm

Also I've created a small program which uses your TreeCheckBox stage to update Table by double-click on cells. I've marked with comments most important places.

```
public class TableCellEditing extends Application {

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 200));
        // you didn't provided data which your Tables use so example will work with Person class
        final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Person("click to edit", "Smith"),
                new Person("", "Johnson"),
                new Person("", "Williams1"),
                new Person("", "Williams2"),
                new Person("", "Williams3"),
                new Person("", "Williams4"),
                new Person("", "Williams5"),
                new Person("", "Jones"),
                new Person("", "Brown"),
                new Person("", "Brown2"));

        TableView tableView = new TableView();
        tableView.setItems(data);
        // make table editable
        tableView.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn();
        lastNameCol.setText("Last");
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("lastName"));


        TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn();
        firstNameCol.setText("First");
        // here you connect data list with table column
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("firstName"));
        // here you specify that your cells are special and provide editing hooks
        firstNameCol.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell call(final TableColumn param) {

                final TableCell cell = new TableCell() {
                    @Override
                    // this method is called on editable tables by double click
                    public void startEdit() {
                        super.startEdit();
                        // here we create new Stage to select items from tree
                        new CheckBoxTreeStage(this).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setText(null);
                        } else {
                            if (isEditing()) {
                                setText(null);
                            } else {
                                // this is the place where we update data by chosen value
                                setText(getItem().toString());
                                setGraphic(null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        });

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol);
        tableView.setFocusTraversable(false);
        root.getChildren().add(tableView);
    }

    // I've extracted your stage to a separate class for better readability
    private static class CheckBoxTreeStage extends Stage {

        private CheckBoxTreeItem<String> checkBoxTreeItem;
        private CheckBoxTreeItem<String> nodeFieldName;
        private CheckBoxTreeItem<String> nodeFieldName2;
        private CheckBoxTreeItem<String> nodeFieldName3;

        public CheckBoxTreeStage(final TableCell cell) {
            CheckBoxTreeItem<String> rootItem =
                    new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Tables");
            rootItem.setExpanded(true);

            final TreeView tree = new TreeView(rootItem);
            tree.setEditable(true);

            tree.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.<String>forTreeView());
            {
                checkBoxTreeItem = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Sample Table");//+ (i+1));                                
                rootItem.getChildren().add(checkBoxTreeItem);
                nodeFieldName = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Field Name1");
                nodeFieldName2 = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Field Name2");
                nodeFieldName3 = new CheckBoxTreeItem<String>("Field Name3");
                checkBoxTreeItem.getChildren().addAll(nodeFieldName, nodeFieldName2, nodeFieldName3);

            }
            tree.setRoot(rootItem);
            tree.setShowRoot(true);
            StackPane root = new StackPane();
            root.getChildren().add(tree);
            Button selectButton = new Button("Select");
            HBox hbox = new HBox();
            hbox.getChildren().add(selectButton);
            hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            selectButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent t) {

                    final ArrayList<String> selectedValues = new ArrayList<String>();
                    //                                    System.out.println("Selected tree items are : ");
                    if (checkBoxTreeItem.isSelected()) {
                        selectedValues.add(checkBoxTreeItem.getValue());
                    }
                    if (nodeFieldName.isSelected()) {
                        selectedValues.add(nodeFieldName.getValue());
                    }
                    if (nodeFieldName2.isSelected()) {
                        selectedValues.add(nodeFieldName2.getValue());
                    }
                    if (nodeFieldName3.isSelected()) {
                        selectedValues.add(nodeFieldName3.getValue());
                    }
                    hide();
                    String selectedVals = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < selectedValues.size(); i++) {
                        if (i == selectedValues.size() - 1) {
                            selectedVals += selectedValues.get(i);
                        } else {
                            selectedVals += selectedValues.get(i) + ",";
                        }
                    }
                    boolean fieldNameChosen = true;
                    if (fieldNameChosen) {
                        cell.commitEdit(selectedVals);
                    } else {
                        cell.cancelEdit();
                    }
                }
            });
            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
            borderPane.setCenter(root);
            borderPane.setBottom(hbox);
            setScene(new Scene(new Group(borderPane)));
        }
    };

    public static class Person {

        private StringProperty firstName;
        private StringProperty lastName;

        private Person(String fName, String lName) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. this one works. Another problem is there with a field where I am just using SimpleStringProperty to display the value. Here there is no update item and yet the values change if I scroll down the tableview.Can you suggest something for this? I am putting the code that I am using to display the value below:

Comment: please, ask another question for that.

Comment: @user1660156. If the answer solves your problem accept it. Else if the answer was useful upvote it. Else if the answer is unrelated or wrong downvote it. See [when should I vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote)  and similar topics please.