# TableView data changes in a field when tableview is scrolled up and down.

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I am getting a problem for a field in my tableview where I need to show values from another table dynamically. Below is the code I have used for updating the cell of the tableview. The table is updated with different values than the ones given to them.

```
              final int k = 0;  
value.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    int noOfDataCells = k;
    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) 
    {                    

        TableColumn column = param.getTableColumn();
        int size = 0;
        if(tableView1.getItems()!=null)
            size = ((ObservableList) tableView1.getItems().get(0)).size();
        String valueFromData = "";
        if(noOfDataCells<size)
        {
            valueFromData = String.valueOf(((ObservableList) tableView1.getItems().get(0)).get(noOfDataCells));                                                               
        }
        else if(noOfDataCells == size)
        {
            noOfDataCells = 0;
            valueFromData = String.valueOf(((ObservableList) tableView1.getItems().get(0)).get(noOfDataCells));  
        }
        else if (noOfDataCells>size)
        {
            valueFromData = "";
        }
        noOfDataCells++;
        return new SimpleStringProperty(valueFromData);

    }
});
```

Comment: you may encountered the same issue as an author of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352305/java-fx-2-2-tableview-data-changes-as-i-scroll-up-and-down-the-tableview/12425646#12425646 Notice that cell become recreated after scrolling out of visible area and back. So your cell factory should be able to create same cell from given data any time.

Comment: This is different since here there is no updateItem() method but still  the data is changing on scrolling up and down the tableview.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this one?